# trying to show image and text when you hover over a graphical element

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I'm trying to show the image, but its not showing and there should be text with the image. I think I need to add some sort of sizing to the image, but still unsure. The graphic is currently just a square but it'll be a dot on a timeline showing significant events, so when hovering over the dot on the timeline an image and text next to it would show the event people want to look at. I found this code on CodePen showing how to hover text, but I tried adding the image but its not showing. I'm new to coding so please be gentle. :)

Edit: So im coding a wedding website and I want to put a "our Story" section, in the section ill have a timeline running down the page and on the line of the timeline would be dots to indicate a significant event that happened. Im trying to get so that an image and text would pop out once someone hovers over these dots.

```css
.reference {
  position: relative;
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.popout-menu {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 100%;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

.reference:hover>.popout-menu,
.reference:focus>.popout-menu,
.reference:focus-within>.popout-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.popoutimg {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="reference" tabindex="0">
  <div class="popout-menu">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="" class="popoutimg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no text in your markup. Why would you expect to see any? Might help if you linked to the source of your code. Also, see [ask]. Your question isn't very specific.

Comment: Would I use <p> to add the text or is there something else I need to use?

Comment: You don't _need_ to use a paragraph element. It's up to you. I'm not clear on your desired outcome. You haven't been very specific.

Comment: I edited it now, I hope that makes it more clearer for everyone

Comment: It's still not clear what the problem is. Why can't you simply replace the image element with your text? Have you tried?

Comment: well im trying to have an image as well as text pop out with the hover effect

Comment: Thank you for asking question which was i looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can just add your text inside the popout-menu div. It should show below your image inside the popup:

```css
.reference {
  position: relative;
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.popout-menu {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 100%;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

.reference:hover>.popout-menu,
.reference:focus>.popout-menu,
.reference:focus-within>.popout-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.popoutimg {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="reference" tabindex="0">
  <div class="popout-menu">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="" class="popoutimg" />

    <div>Your text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should copy the snippet down here and make changes to demonstrate your solution.

Comment: Thanks, But Let me go through it.